# Visual Studio 2015: What does "Suppression State" column in "Error List" window indicate?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

**Visual Studio 2015**: What does "**Suppression State**" column in "**Error List**" window indicate?

Answer (score 5):

It has something to do with Code Analysis. It states if a warning had been suppressed by the #Disable Warning pragma. The state of a warning is either active or suppressed if it's enclosed in a pragma.

There is a good explanation on the MSDN forum:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cfd25c9-8bc3-4d70-b463-cfe861e2d78c/what-is-suppression-state-in-vs2015?forum=visualstudiogeneral